# Query results showing twice while using aliases?

Tags: mysql, join, duplicates

I have a query that I am running in MySQL, and it uses aliases to grab information from the same column twice (to and from destinations from the `airport` table).

```
`SELECT AirlineName AS 'Airline Name',
     airport1.AirportName AS 'Flying From',
     airport2.AirportName AS 'Flying To',
     StopType AS 'Number of Stops'
FROM flightjunction
INNER JOIN airline ON flightjunction.FlightAirline = airline.AirlineID
INNER JOIN airport AS airport1 ON flightjunction.FlightFrom = airport1.AirportID
INNER JOIN airport AS airport2 ON flightjunction.FlightTo = airport2.AirportID
INNER JOIN stops ON flightjunction.FlightStops = stops.StopID;`
```

However, I've noticed that duplicate results are showing up when I run this query.  Where am I going wrong?  Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have an inner join on the same table twice in this case, you should add a DISTINCT to eliminate duplicates.

Comment: Cheers, please set to accepted answer if this solved your problem :)